# Idle speed is wrong after replacing battery (2006 Camry)

Tags: toyota, rough-idle, camry, idle, power-loss

I have a 2006 Toyota Camry. I replaced the battery the other day which I noticed was getting weak. The battery was disconnected all of 10 minutes.

After, it idles too low. It shudders pretty bad and even killed itself once. If my foot is on the gas pedal there's no problem. I've put maybe 100 miles on it since and it is slightly better. It has not killed since. But the idle seems slow still, and there is still a shimmy.

Will this work itself out as a computer or sensor somewhere adjusts something or relearns something? Is there an easy way to adjust idle speed if not? I've never heard of something like this before.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! There may be a relearn procedure for the computer after battery replacement. It may work itself out, but not sure. I'm just making a comment, as I'd bet @Ben may know the answer to this for sure. Others may know as well.

Comment: I would start with giving the throttle body a good cleaning.  It may be that the pcm has compensated for a dirty throttle body over time, and with the battery disconnected, it has lost its compensated values, and now thinks it is brand new and perfectly clean.

Comment: See this....https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ZRjcJOSFW0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clean the throttle and perform an idle relearn. Unfortunately there isn’t a reset function in Techstream or other software, you can only do it manually. This is the way I do it, some people say to hold the throttle plate closed on the first key on. I find it to be unnecessary and tends to lead to having to do the procedure multiple times.

First you need to disconnect the battery. Short the cable ends together for a several minutes and pull the etcs fuse in the underhood fusebox.

Take this opportunity to clean the throttle assembly, make sure there isn’t any buildup. Don’t spray anything into the throttle assembly. It’s all too possible to over saturate the assembly and ruin a throttle position sensor. Wet a rag and use it to wipe away. You can also use a small brush to help.

Put the fuse back in, reconnect the battery. Key on engine off for 10 seconds and start the engine. Let it warm up without any loads on (e.g. the blower motor). Once it hits closed loop you should be good to go.